# Help with understanding how to find sum of series

Tags: sequences-and-series

Find the sum to $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(n+1)(n+2)}{3^n}x^n$

I do this:

$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^n=\frac{1}{1-x}$ I then take the derivative twice and get

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}nx^{n-1}$

$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}(n-1)nx^{n-2}$ And the change the sum index to n=0 and get and

$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (n+1)(n+2)x^n=\frac{2}{(1-x)^3}$ and substitute $x$ for $x/3$.

$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(n+1)(n+2)}{3^n} x^n=\frac{2}{(1-x/3)^3}=\frac{54}{(3-x)^3}$

But my question is, why do I not get the same answer if I substitute from the beginning?

$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (x/3)^n=\frac{1}{1-x/3}=\frac{3}{3-x}$

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n(x/3)^{n-1}=\frac{3}{(3-x)^2}$

$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} (n-1)n (x/3)^{n-2}=\frac{6}{(3-x)^3}$

$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(n+1)(n+2)}{3^n} x^n=\frac{6}{(3-x)^3}$

When should one substitute in general to get the right answer? Before or after all the different operations?

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Comment: I shall remember next time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your derivative on the LHS is wrong.

$$
\begin{split}
\frac{d}{dx} \left(\frac{x}{3}\right)^n &= n (x/3)^{n-1} \frac13\\
\frac{d}{dx} \left[\frac{d}{dx} \left(\frac{x}{3}\right)^n \right]
    &= n (n-1) (x/3)^{n-2} \frac19.
\end{split}
$$

That factor of $1/9$ is what you are missing: $$\frac{6}{1/9} = 54$$

Comment: I see that now! Thank you so much for your help! :)

Answer (score 2):

Let $$g(x)=\frac{1}{1-x}.$$

If $$F(x)=g(\frac xa)$$ where $a\ne 0$, then

$$F'(x)=\frac 1a g'(\frac xa)$$
and

$$F''(x)=\frac{1}{a^2}g''(\frac xa)$$

So, with $a=3$, we get

$$F''(x)=\frac 19\frac{54}{(1-x)^3}=\frac{6}{(1-x)^3}$$

Comment: Ohh, of course. Thank you so much!